# Can I capture and save the current state of a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I need to get the entire contents of a page with javascript and send it to a server script to save it. I want to do this after the user has made some changes to the page using AJAX and other javascript tools. I don't want the state of certain elements. I'd like to essentially get everything inside the body tag so I can pass it to a server-side script. I have tried getelementbyid etc. but it seems to put the page in a loop and crashes.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you are referring to?

Comment: I think you can talk the tree starting from the HTML node and get all the info and send to your own site using Javascript, if the page is also your own website's page.  But doing so is almost like starting Firefox by saving all the RAM and OS data into the hard drive and restoring it (like Hibernating the computer).  It usually is best if you save some state or flags and store those, and re-render the page accordingly.  Or use AJAX Bookmark and History if that's why you need.

Comment: Seems like I did, some great suggestions that i will try a soon as get a little time. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var bodycontent = body[0];
```

Then use "bodycontent.innerHTML" to retrieve the contents of it.  If I'm not mistaken, it should provide the body's current content, after any javascript modifications that have been made to it.

Comment: alternatively, "body[0].innerHTML" would work, if you wanted to eliminate the "bodycontent" variable, or if you wanted to be very terse, you could simply use "document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML" to access the contents without using any variables -- it works, but is somewhat less easy to read ;)

Comment: fantastic I will try these today!

Comment: Will this save the changes to all JavaScript functions and variables as well? In some cases, persistent storage of JavaScript variables might be necessary.

Comment: Here's how to get the values of all JavaScript variables, so that they can be saved to a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762075/get-all-javascript-variables

Comment: It is worth noting that getElementsByTagName() returns a live HTMLCollection and querySelectorAll() returns a static NodeList. The [difference matters](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/ "Explanation of the difference between getElementsByTagName vs querySelectorAll.") and is easy to overlook / not think about.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, if you want to.  There's an element of the DOM tree called 'document' containing the whole document.  There are ways to translate a DOM tree to HTML in most libraries; applying that to the `document` node should do the job.

Some hacking about long those lines should get you on the right track.

But do you *really* need to do that?  Why?

Comment: Well..it's kinda crazy..but it occured to me that i could make an extremely lazy CMS for a static site. I'll just put ckeditor on each page when the user is done making changes I'll save the entire page back as a static html page.versioning should be easy to, just add some basic login and done.

Comment: Not crazy at all, that's basically how a wiki works.  Should be fun to see; let me know.

Comment: How would you use the dom tree to save the state of all JavaScript variables on the page?

Comment: The name space for all the variables is some dictionary somewhere; if nowhere else, it's hanging off 'window'.

Answer (score 2):

It should work simply like this:

**javascript:**    document.body.innerHTML;

**jquery:** $("body").innerHTML