# How to get all javascript variables with a single function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dom

I want to get all the variables which are set on DOM before with a single function. 
I am not sure it is possible in javascript or not.

```
var a= 1;
var b=2;
var =3;

var all_data= get_all_vars();

function get_all_vars(){
//this function should return 
// return array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3);
}
```

Please suggest me the answer. Either it is possible or not. If it is possible how to do it?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762075/get-all-javascript-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
for(i in window) console.log(i);
```

or

```
Object.keys(window)
```

but it'll return every global variable. There's no way to do exactly what you want, unfortunately.

Comment: @thefourtheye Impossible to say, it depends on the context of the code in the question. If it was literally just that inside of a `<script>` tag then yes, they'd be global (even though they used the `var` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

```
//el is your DOM object
 function get_all_vars(el){
      var ret = {};
      for(p in el){
        if(el.hasOwnProperty(p)){
           ret[p]=el[p]; 
        }
      }
      return ret; 
    }
```