# JavaScript iterating through all variables in Page

Tags: javascript

I wanted to get all JavaScript Variables. So I followed instructions in this topic and it worked smoothly.

[Get all Javascript Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762075/get-all-javascript-variables)

Now I also want to get all strings, that are not declared as variable. For example in below code when I iterate through **this** I get the value of variable **hello** in output. However, since **"Passing My Message"** string is not declared as variable, I don't get this string in output.

```
<script>
function MyFunction(msg){
    alert('Message Passed : '+msg)
}
var hello = "AAA";
MyFunction("Passing My Message");

for (i in this){
    console.log(i + " : " + eval(i));
}
</script>
```

Now my question is, is there any way I can get the **Passing My Message** string in output.

Comment: No, there is not. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: your loop logs just what belongs to the window object, so, there's no way to log something that isn't stored.

Comment: It's not a variable, so no. But if you've hardcoded that literal beforehand, then you will know that it exists. Or you could remove the hardcoding, if you have some requirement to look at variables on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You won't. When you call the function `MyFunction` it creates the variable `msg`. When the function finishes the variable `msg` is removed.

If you checked inside the `MyFunction` function then you would see the `msg` variable but you won't see it at any other time.

Comment: When I insert for (i in this){console.log(i);} just after the MyFunction() starts (before alert), I still don't see the msg variable. :(