# How to select a variable by a substring with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variable-names

I have more than 10 javascript variables which change every time the page is refreshed.
I would like to select this variable:

```js
var layer_control_e69649c5e9f941908fcc3173d4dee734 = {
  base_layers: {},
  overlays: {
    "Roads": geo_json_e8253853662b46f985f09f9f27be4df9,
    "Intersections": feature_group_d2005a626dee4cb6ac241e03e5110145,
  },
};
```

Only `layer_control` doesnt not change. The string `e69649c5e9f941908fcc3173d4dee734` changes every time the page is refreshed. I would like select this variable using the constant string `layer_control`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why exactly did you tag `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell more about how this variable is created and how you are planing to use it? Without further information's I would just suggest to push the variables directly from the input stream into an array. Then you can just point on the position of the variable instead of knowing the name.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a regex pattern to [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for the variable name in the appropriate scope. Below, I'm [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#global_context) (`this`) for a key that starts with "layout_control_".

```js
var layer_control_e69649c5e9f941908fcc3173d4dee734 = {
  base_layers: {},
  overlays: {
    "Roads": "test",
    "Intersections": "test",
  },
};

var varname = Object.keys(this).filter(
  key => /^layer_control_/.test(key)
)[0];

console.log(varname);
console.log(this[varname] ?? 'n/a');
```

For reference, see:
[Get all Javascript Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762091/924299)